# Access functions in bootstrap.js from options XUL page

Tags: firefox-addon

I am developing Firefox Bootstrapped Addon. 
This addon should be managed using toolbar button and standard options page (options.xul in my case). So I need to access functions in bootstrap.js from my options.xul page.

Is it possible to do so?

I want to avoid code duplication in bootstrap.js and options page.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct access from your xul windows/pages to bootstrap.js.

However, there are multiple ways to achieve your goal anyway:

- You could use [Javascript Code Modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules) to implement common functionality and import such modules as needed in bootstap.js and/or your xul windows. (Don't forget to `Cu.unload` your modules on shutdown)
- You could script your xul windows the same way you would listen for and script `browser.xul` to add and drive your toolbar buttons.
- You could push [own observer notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIObserverService#notifyObservers%28%29) in your windows and listen for them in your bootstrap.js (e.g. the add-on SDK `simple-prefs` module will essentially do exactly this for buttons).